# Select unique values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have created a query to filter data. I need to select only distinct inv_mast_uid in final statement. I need to select only 1 row if same inv_mast_uid repeats. Please suggest

```
with s1
     as (select count(supplier_part_no)as count_of_duplicates,
                supplier_part_no,
                supplier_id,
                inv.item_desc,
                extended_desc
         from   p21_view_inventory_supplier supp
                join p21_view_inv_mast inv
                  on supp.item_id = inv.item_id
         where  product_type = 'R'
                and supp.delete_flag = 'N'
                and inv.delete_flag = 'N'
                and other_charge_item = 'N'
         group  by supplier_part_no,
                   supplier_id,
                   item_desc,
                   extended_desc
         having count(supplier_part_no) > 1),
     s2 as (select supp.inv_mast_uid,
                inv.item_id,
                supplier_id,
                supplier_part_no,
                item_desc,
                extended_desc
         from   p21_view_inventory_supplier supp
                left join p21_view_inv_mast inv
                       on supp.item_id = inv.item_id)
select s2.inv_mast_uid,
       s2.item_id,
       count_of_duplicates,
       s1.supplier_part_no,
       s1.supplier_id,
       s1.extended_desc,
       s1.item_desc
from   s2
       join s1
         on s1.supplier_part_no = s2.supplier_part_no
where  s1.supplier_id = s2.supplier_id
       and s1.item_desc = s2.item_desc
       and ( s1.extended_desc = s2.extended_desc
              or s1.extended_desc is null
                 and s2.extended_desc is null )
```

result is

[image: query output]

expected result:

wants to have only line 1 and line 2.  without affecting other group by functions.

added code and related output.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. And please format your query in a way that makes it readable - as it stands its a wall of text which makes no sense at all.

Comment: And why have you tagged PLSQL which is Oracle, as well as SQL Server?

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle's dialect, not SQL Server's. SQL Server uses T-SQL. Also, are you *really* using 2008? 2008 has been completely unsupported for over 2 years now.

Comment: And, as @DaleK said, White space and line breaks are an invaluable resource when writing (and I don't just mean code). Learn to use it. If you have a *single line* of code that is over **1,500** characters long (yours is 1,539 including white space), you have gone *very **very*** wrong.

Comment: Guys using stack after long time. Sorry for the wrong tags and un uniformed code block.

Comment: am I missing something? will not 'DISTINCT' solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use distinct. It will return distinct rows on the basis of columns you're selecting. That is, duplicate rows will be removed.

```
select distinct s2.inv_mast_uid as inv_mast_uid,
   s2.item_id,
   count_of_duplicates,
   s1.supplier_part_no,
   s1.supplier_id as supplier_id,
   s1.extended_desc,
   s1.item_desc
from   s2
   join s1
     on s1.supplier_part_no = s2.supplier_part_no
where  s1.supplier_id = s2.supplier_id
   and s1.item_desc = s2.item_desc
   and ( s1.extended_desc = s2.extended_desc
          or (s1.extended_desc is null
             and s2.extended_desc is null) )
```

I guess you've put the wrong parenthesis in the last line, so added that there in the `or` condition.

BUT, if you're looking for distinct value of only the column `inv_mast_uid` and do not bother about what values on other columns, you can do this:

Put the last select as `s3`, then write the select as follows:

```
select p.* 
    from s3 as p
inner join (select inv_mast_uid, min(supplier_id) from
s3 group by s2.inv_mast_uid) as q
on p.inv_mast_uid= q.inv_mast_uid
    and p.supplier_id = q.supplier_id
```